# Restoring messages from ClockworkMod backup

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms, backup, clockworkmod-recovery

Here's the story. Today my phone (modded with Cyanogen mod) started bootlooping. So, I did a ClockworkMod backup and went about installing the latest version of Cyanogen mod. When that was done, I restored the backup, but it started bootlooping yet again. So now, I have a fresh install of Cyanogen mod but none of my texts or call logs etc, all my contacts were sync'd from my Facebook anyway so I can get them back easily.

Does anyone know how I can extract my text messages from the ClockworkMod backup without sending my device back into a bootloop?

Cheers!

Comment: This won't help you currently, but something to consider for the future: if you find yourself switching ROMs frequently, you can try an SMS backup application like [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) which backs up your messages to an XML on your SD card, or [SMS Backup+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync) which syncs your messages and call logs to your Google account (essentially as GMail messages).

Answer (score 3):

Use [Titanium Backup pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) (Paid). It can restore individual apps+data from CWM backups!

It clearly colors data containers with Green. And, names of container which keep contacts etc. vary as per Android version & manufacturer, but they are generally human readable. Keep Green color in mind. If you find Contacts which is not colored with green, its app.. not data container.