# Extract App Data from Nandroid / CWM Backup

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, data-recovery, restore, nandroid

I use ClockworkMod Recovery, and Slimbean.

Recently, my slimbean started hanging at the loading screen and getting insanely hot. So I took a backup, and cleaned flashed AOKP rom. It's working fine so far. Initially, I tried to do a flash without clearing data. Then, a clean flash with "advanced restore"ing the data alone from the backup, but both resulted in the above-mentioned problem of hanging at boot screen.

Is there a way to extract the app-data from CWM backup and restore it manually? Or an app for this?

Comment: See if the answer here works: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20738/restoring-messages-from-clockworkmod-backup I can't vouch for it, because I don't have CWM. Let us know if it worked. :)

Comment: @geffchang sounds like it might, but too expensive :(

Comment: It's a very good investment though. I use it for my back-ups. And it can also do several other things other than back-ups. :)

Comment: See also: [View/mount Nandroid file on Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/44810/16575) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the well-known [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) app (for which you must purchase the [Pro key](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) to unlock the CWM/TWRP nandroid backup support), there is another app now: [Nandroid Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore), which according to its description can restore apps from nandroid backups even with the free version (there is a [Pro key](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore.pro) too, but it is required if you want to restore special data such as Wi-Fi access points, Bluetooth data, user dictionary and browser data). However, I did not try using this app.

Comment: Thanks, That looks interesting, I will try it out tonight.

Comment: Its quite slow, but it seems to be working. Have restored sms-calllogs, working on app data right now. Thanks again!

Comment: It worked for many apps, but notably apps that I had installed on internal SD card ( ~90% of games) dont seem to have been backed up.. that was dissapointing..

Comment: Nandroid manager did not work at all for me. (Backup was found, but was restorable). Titanium Pro worked for apps not moved via Link2SD.

Answer (score 3):

[Titanium Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) can do that.

> [✔] Restore individual apps+data from CWM backups!

[Similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20738/restoring-messages-from-clockworkmod-backup).

Comment: That requires the $6.99 PRO key for TB.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are several options, though I was hoping for something simple like "rename to .tar and open in 7-zip". Anyway, some options:

- on the phone, install [Nandroid Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore) or [Yaffs Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.wdscript.yaffsexplorer), or pay to install [Titanium Backup Pro](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/24674/109855) (which is a frequently recommended app anyway)
- on a Linux computer, use [`unyaffs`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28594/109855), or go to lots of trouble but get the yaffs fs [mounted](http://tjworld.net/wiki/Linux/Kernel/SimulateNandMtdDevice) for real:

See also this very [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24664/how-do-i-access-img-files-with-yaffs2).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers have become a bit dated so here is an update: Nandroid Manager doesn't seem to be developed any more and doesn't work reliably with the latest versions of Android anymore. But it's worth a try. In my case, about half of my apps were successfully restored and for most of the ones where "restore app + data" failed, **"restore data" alone worked** (and you can just reinstall the app from the app store).

As regards Titanium Backup Pro, it is still updated but the "Restore from Nandroid" function doesn't seem to work too well either on Marshmallow. Over the past months, there have been multiple reports of it either not seeing the backup files at all or failing to read their contents. [I guess it's not a priority for the developers to fix this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145865/why-doesnt-anybody-develop-apps-to-partially-restore-nandroid-backups-anymore).

Comment: I second this... I could not restore any of my apps with Titanium Backup on my new Oneplus Three (Coming from a Oneplus One)

Comment: Nandroid Manager doesn't even exist anymore. Any other options?