# Restoring one application data from ClockModRecovery Backup

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, restore, whatsapp-messenger

I was using CyanogenMod 4.10.3. Due to slow-downs I decided to downgrade, but took a backup of all available apps using ClockModRecovery including WhatsApp.

In backup/ directory, I see some img files, not individual apps.

Since I changed my number and I would like to use my old number with WhatsApp, I would like to restore WhatsApp backup from this backup. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is:

- [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) can restore from [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backups (which is what CWM created)
- [AppExtractor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/AppExtractor/com.handyandy.appextractor) can extract individual apps/data from Nandroid backups
- [Nandroid Browser](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Nandroid-Browser/de.goddchen.android.nandroidbrowser) lets you... guess what :)
- and then there's [Nandroid Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Nandroid-Manager-ROOT/com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore) to browse them, restore single items, etc.

Further readings:

- the [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info)
- [Restore only part of nandroid image](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7851/16575)
- [Extract App Data from Nandroid / CWM Backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49707/16575)

Comment: Woow. Very nice explanation. AppExtractor helped a lot :). Thanks,