# Unable to restore contacts through Titanium Backup after flashing a custom ROM

Tags: custom-roms, data-recovery, titanium-backup

I flashed the 4.2.2 version of CyanogenMod onto my Galaxy S4 and had backed up my stock using ClockworkMod. I have been able to use Titanium Backup Pro to restore pretty much everything except my contacts. I think the issue is with my old contacts being stored in a newer version of Android. Is there any way to restore them? I would really like my contacts back

I had tried flashing with a stock ROM but the latest one I can get from SamMobile is 4.2.2. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: How did you try to restore contacts with *TiBu*? You just should make sure to have "migration mode" enabled to avoid trouble (changed database formats and the like). This setting is located in the "troubleshooting" section, if I remember correctly. In the very same section, it might be useful to also ensure the system's SQLite is used (and not TiBu's own).

Comment: I am trying to restore using TiBu from a CWM backup I created. I have tried adding those two settings in TiBu that you suggested but it doesnt make any difference. Once the restore is complete of the contacts and contacts storage I get 'Unfortunately, the process android.process.acore has stopped' and the only way I can get rid of it is by clearing the data from the apps.

Comment: Did you restart your device after the restore? That's required when restoring "central data" (like contacts, SMS, WiFi passwords, and the like).

Comment: Yes I did that too as it is recommended by Titanium Backup after restore is complete. Have tried the whole process a few times.

Comment: OK, that seems to leave you with your Nandroid backup from CWM. Please take a look at [Extract App Data from Nandroid / CWM Backup](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49707/16575) / [Restore only part of nandroid image](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7851/16575), hopefully those will hold some value. Apart from that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Okay thats great I will check that out thanks